# MySQL What happens if we set back SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1 in a table with invalid data?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb

What actually happens when `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0`, then we add some invalid rows with, or add a foreign key to a table then set back `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1` while some rows have invalid data?

Will the index just be ignored? Will everything function normally and there will just be no relation?

My guess is that nothing will change but if we try to edit the row and save it, an error will pop.. Is that right? I can't really confirm this looking in the docs.

**EDIT:**
I want to know precisely if anything below the surface might be broken. The data might appear ok when looking at the table but I'm not sure if something would be missing somewhere. I believe foreign checks are made only when inserts/deletes/updates are executed, but I'm worried something else I don't know about might break while I do these operations.

I'm just asking for advice from people who have more expertise than me for god's sake. I didn't know this would be asking for the moon.

Comment: I mean internally @fancyPants.. Not sure if MySQL has some sort of pointers or low-level variables when using foreign keys

Comment: Try it out and you will see. Simple as that.

Comment: I TRIED ALREADY!!! I know what happens to the rows, they stay the same, I am asking what will happens INTERNALLY, if there are any sort of pointers

Comment: Calm down, okay? And you haven't noticed that nothing happens? So what do you expect? The only way you notice something, is when your data integrity is corrupted, for example when you have children without parents. Nothing more. An insert statement might fail or something. Nothing else happens.

Comment: Thanks! If you care to write as an answer I'll accept your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you notice something, is when your data integrity is corrupted, for example when you have children without parents. An insert statement might fail or something. Nothing else happens.